# Building SSO application with SAML or OPENID in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, openid, saml, cas, symfony-2.3

We are using symfony2 as our framework to built the application which has different firewalls like admin, client and customer.

Now I want to built SSO using SAML(CAS) or OPENID in symfony2. Which will communicate with my application and provide the authentication and with other applications also through web service.

Please suggest some bundles which are already built for SSO and which is better SAML or OPENID.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

I'm not sure if you want to use CAS, SAML or OpenID protocols, but here is an example of a CAS client for Symfony: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Symfony+CAS+Client. It might help.

Comment: Thanks for the sharingt the information, Actually I m looking for various option to build SSO server using SYMFONY. And we are thinking to adopt OpenId as the protocol.